# How to pick random cars in python from txt file

Tags: python, random

i've came across this problem that i've been trying to solve: i want to use a txt to randomly pick a car from a txt file but i always get it wrong and i  hoped that you could help me here is what i have done so far in this specific part:

```
import random

if user_input == "1":

  with open("cars.txt", "r") as call_uber:

      for line in call_uber:

          array1 = line.split(" : ")

          print(array1)
```

the objective is to randomly pick the first name of one of the txt file lines
but i just managed to split them

ps: i'm a newbie at this.

Comment: can you give the format in which car nam eis store in text file

Comment: If you want to randomly choose a line, use `line = random.choice(call_uber.readlines())` and then do `array1 = line.split(" : ")`

Comment: its working now thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To randomly pick a line, just add ***random.choice*** function :

```
import random

if user_input == "1":

    with open("cars.txt", "r") as call_uber:

        line = random.choice(call_uber.readlines())

        array1 = line.split(" : ")

        print(array1)
```

Comment: No prob ! Don’t Forget to validate ;) have a nice coding !